# filter ip from message string in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using ELK to push /var/log/secure logs.
On giving wrong password, we receive below logs in our secure logs"

```
   "Failed password for invalid user cds-eng from 32.97.110.55 port 8023 ssh2"
```

I want to add the ip address as a field along with message string in logs.
my logstash config file is as below

```
 input {
lumberjack {
port => 5050
type => "logs"
ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
 }
 }
 filter {
   kv {
add_field => { "remote_ip" => "%{IP}" }
 }
 }
 output {
   elasticsearch {
    hosts => "127.0.0.1:9200"
}
}
```

I am using logstash 2.0.
I tried using the IP pattern of logstash but it is not working.
Any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the grok{} filter to parse your message up into fields.  That's where you'd use the %{IP} pattern.  It's easiest to test this at the [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/).  grok{} can add the field for you, so there would be no need for the add_field later.

Also, the kv{} filter is going to try and split your message up based on key/value pairs, which you don't seem to have.

Comment: grok{} parse message into fields, I want message string also with the fields. So how can I have push both things to elasticsearch.

Comment: grok{} won't overwrite the 'message' field unless you ask it to do so.

Comment: I tried below configuration but it is not working.

`                      input {
                      lumberjack {
    port => 5050
    type => "logs"
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }
}
filter {

grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{IP:client}" }
}
  kv {
    add_field => { "remote_ip" => "client" }

}
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "127.0.0.1:9200"
                 }
              }`

Comment: If by "it", you mean that "remote_ip" is being set to the literal "client" instead of the IP address grok'ed from the message, it's because "client" is a literal.  Try "%{client}".

Comment: Did  this grok `grok { match => { "message" => "%{IP:client}" } }` given you the IP from `Failed password for invalid user cds-eng from 32.97.110.55 port 8023 ssh2` log ?
I am also trying to extract IP from any string using grok.